# Add additional validation for logins using LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle

Tags: lexikjwtauthbundle

I want to add additional validation to allow the login, ie, not just check that the username and password match but do other validations on the user before allowing him to login.

I tried extending JWTTokenAuthenticator but it seems none of its methods are called during the login.

I thought of using a custom "AuthenticationSuccessHandler" but I'm not sure if this is the place I should do this and how could I report from there that the "login" is actually invalid.

Where should I put this logic?

Answer (score 0):

I end up replacing the "login_form" authentication shown on the LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle bundle documentation for a custom guard authentication just for the login, i.e. different than the guard authentication used to validate the JWT tokens.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I had a similar requirement. Within the alternatives I chose to implement a custom user provider. [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html) on custom user provider creation is more than enough to accomplish the task. Moreover, "[Configuring the user provider](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/8-jwt-user-provider.md#configuring-the-user-provider)" section of the LexikJwt documentation explains how to configure lexik_jwt accordingly.